# Combine files in a filegroup SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to combine files in a filegroup in SQL Server 2005. How do I do this? I've run the EMPTYFILE DBCC Shrinkfile but it's crawling..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (for the tables at least) would be to drop the clustered index and then re-create the clustered index specifying the filegroup you are trying to combine them into.  Since the clustered index is applied to the actual table this would accomplish what you are trying to do (for the tables).

You can read more about this approach on this MSDN forum topic.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/043c2bd4-07a1-4361-8c2b-7f375dd72107